# Define method in a separate file with attributes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, oop

As you know we can define class definition and method definition in separate files in `@folder`. How we can do that if we have attributes for method? I read in MATLAB OOP documentation that we should use this structure in method file:

```
classdef myClass
  method (att = value,...)
    tdata = testdata(obj,arg1,arg2)
 end 
end
```

But we have another file (`myClass`) in this folder for class definition so if we have this structure we have two class definition files. one of them has properties definition and another has methods properties (two files with same name!). If we change above `classdef` name(myClass) to function name(testdata), we have a error in MATLAB. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

If you're defining your class using an `@`-folder and separate files, you don't need two class definition files. You need a single class definition file (which is basically as you've defined in your question) and a separate file that contains just your method, implemented as a function.

For example:

**@MyClass\MyClass.m**

```
classdef MyClass
    properties (GetAccess = public, SetAccess = private)
        myGreeting
    end
    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = MyClass
            obj.myGreeting= 'hello'
        end
        function sayhello(obj, name)
            txt = obj.getText(name);
            disp(txt)
        end
    end
    methods (Access = private)
        txt = getText(obj, name)
    end
end
```

**@MyClass\getText.m**

```
function txt = getText(obj, name)
    txt = [obj.myGreeting, ' ', name];
end
```

Note that you only need to include the stub definition of the method within the class definition file if you need to modify the method attributes from default. If it's a public method (and non-Static, non-Hidden, non-Sealed, non-Abstract etc), you don't need to include it at all, you just need to include the file in the `@`-folder.